# How do I get the entire body text of my questions, answers, and comments from API requests?

Tags: support, questions, api, timeline

I tried `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/MY USER ID/timeline?sort=creation&page=1&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow`, then `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/MY USER ID/timeline?sort=creation&page=2&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow` and continued to do the same requests incrementing page numbers until the API got to the last smaller page of data. I got an array called "items" that contained all of my questions, comments, answers, etc... but no body text.

I figured maybe if I requested "questions" individually it would give me the body text and then I could repeat this process for answers and comments. I ran `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/QUESTION ID 1;QUESTION ID 2;QUESTION ID 3;MORE QUESTION IDS SEPARATED BY SEMI COLONS ETC...?site=stackoverflow` and the result still didn't have body text.

So how can I do a query that actually gives me the body text of my questions, answers, and/or comments?

Comment: Do you want the markdown content or do you want the rendered HTML content?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113204/getting-the-body-of-a-question-or-answer-through-api

Comment: This comment in the post you liked worked! https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175264/1373918. I would prefer markdown and appending `filter=withbody` gives me an HTML body but it's still amazing if this is the only option.

Comment: You can make a custom filter to get the markdown body as described in one of the linked answers

Comment: It should also be possible to use SEDE: something like `select * from Posts where UserID = <your id>`, and then download the CSV of the results. I did that (not sure of the exact details) recently and it works fine. However, the post bodies will be rendered HTML, not Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `withbody` filter or explicitly select the body field in the question type.

Do note the `/users/{id}/timeline` returns a [`user_timeline`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user-timeline) type in the `items` collection and there is no body field of the question/answer on that type. So you first collect all `post_id` for `post_type == 'question'` and then call the `/questions/{ids}` endpoint adding the filter query parameter set to value `withbody`.

Or alternatively create a custom filter to just get the body field:

[image: Filter dropdown in edit mode, showing question expanded with body and body_markdown fields checked]

And after you clicked save you'll find the filter value at the top:

[image: saved filter shows filter value in right top corner]

And you can click Edit again to make more adjustments.

Not that on the types page in the documentation, for example for [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) a green checkmark means the field is part of the default filter and a red cross means the field is **not** part of the default filter. Filters are further explained [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) where we also learn that `withbody` is the `default` filter plus the `.body` fields.

Here is a proof of concept in JavaScript where I use the two endpoints from your question to ultimately list the question bodies from the post_ids as found in your timeline.

```js
const userid = 13215988
const page = 1
const pagesize = 15
const site = 'stackoverflow'
const filter = 'withbody'
const timelineUrl = `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/${userid}/timeline?sort=creation&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}&site=${site}` 

function createItem(item) {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  const qbody = document.createElement('div')
  qbody.innerHTML = item.body
  div.appendChild(qbody);
  div.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  return div
}

function processQuestions(items) {
  const root = document.getElementById('root')
  for(const item of items) {
    root.appendChild(createItem(item));
  }   
}

function processTimeline(items) {
  const questions = []
  for(const item of items) {
        if (item.post_type === 'question') {
            questions.push(item.post_id);
        }
  }
    return questions;
}

function getQuestions(questions) {
  const questionUrl = `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/${questions.join(';')}?sort=creation&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}&site=${site}&filter=${filter}` 
  return getApi(questionUrl)
}
    
function getApi(url) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => json.items)
}
    
getApi(timelineUrl)
  .then(processTimeline)
    .then(getQuestions)
    .then(processQuestions);
```

```html
<div id="root">
</div>
```